# How to implement code container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How can I implement a code view widget as pub dev provides for copying sample code.

I want to implement the same functionality in the flutter app.

[image]

Comment: What about checking https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev for the code they used and using it

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude thanks but the hosted site is using HTML code.

Comment: okay. well, it will be worth building such a widget from scratch and maybe publishing it to pub.dev so anybody can use it as a package. But I suppose, it will take the full indented code as argument, then the widget will render it with richtext combinations and use different color schemes for different Dart literals. Is that okay? let me work on such then